# Can't Load Caret Library in RStudio

Tags: r, macos, r-caret

I am having trouble loading the Caret library. Using RStudio on Mac. I get the following error:

[image]

Comment: I even tried installing "robustbase" and nothing worked.

Comment: Did you try reinstalling caret?

Comment: Try to run installed.packages() function to see which dependencies are missing? Is robustbase pacakge in the list of installed packages? Specify lib.loc parameter there too. Also is your lib.loc directory on the Path to R to find it. You can check it using .libPaths() function. Notice the dot in front of the name of the function.

Comment: Hi all, yes I have tried reinstalling it with "install.packages("caret", dependencies = TRUE)". And the library location is: "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library"

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue. After install.packages("robustbase", dependencies=TRUE), you are prompted with "Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation?". I was saying "y". Turns out "n" gets robustbase to install correctly which then gets caret to work.